# How to number of entries in one column that satisfy condition from another column?

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this:

```
head(m,20)

         snp1      snp2    r2
1   rs7278528 rs7278528 1.000
2    rs234750 rs7278528 0.841
3    rs413621 rs7278528 0.841
4    rs413624 rs7278528 0.568
5   rs4920017 rs7278528 0.841
6    rs393280 rs7278528 0.821
7   rs1788470 rs7278528 0.568
8  rs10887972 rs7278528 0.568
9    rs439861 rs7278528 0.568
10  rs1672133 rs7278528 0.841
11   rs370994 rs7278528 0.841
12   rs442981 rs7278528 0.841   
...
```

I would like to calculate and output in a separate column for each unique value in snp2, how many snp1 have r2 > 0.8

I tired doing this but no success:

```
m %>%
  group_by(snp1) %>%
  summarize(sumR2 = sumRows(snp1[r2>0.8]))
```

#### UPDATE

this solved my problem:

```
t <- filter(m, r2 >= 0.8) %>% group_by(snp1) %>% mutate(ldbuds = length(r2))
```

Comment: Protip: if you describe your problem as *"for each unique value in `snp2`"*, you almost certainly want `group_by(snp2)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the description, we may need to group by 'snp2', extract the 'snp1' that corresponds to where 'r2' is greater than 0.8 and get the length of unique elements of 'snp1'

```
library(tidyverse)
m %>%
  group_by(snp2) %>%
  summarize(sumR2 = n_distinct(snp1[r2>0.8]))
```

Or it could be

```
m %>% 
   group_by(snp2) %>%
   summarise(sumR2 =  sum(r2 > 0.8, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0):

if you could include reproducible example of your data would be nice!

But ths should work, if you are trying to group by snp2

```
m %>%
  group_by(snp2) %>%
  summarize(sumR2 = n_distinct(r2>0.8))
```